# Two lists and statement

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda

Here is my code, I want to get result contains b and c but it gives me error.

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:Test 0926.xlsx')

df.drop_duplicates(['mention'],inplace=True)

a = df['mention'].str.lower()
searchfor =[some words in it]

b = a[a.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
opposite = [some words in it]

c = a[a.str.contains('|' .join(opposite))]
def check_it(sentences):
    if b and c in sentences:
        return sentences

d = a.apply(lambda x:check_it(x))
print(d)
```

Any one can help with this?

Comment: Please add the error you receive to your question.

Comment: ...and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask while you're at it. Currently your code gives a number of opportunities for errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to chain both boolean masks and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'mention':['this is nice', 'nice', 'this is nice and bad', 'this is bad']
})

print (df)
                mention
0          this is nice
1                  nice
2  this is nice and bad
3           this is bad

df.drop_duplicates(['mention'],inplace=True)

a = df['mention'].str.lower()
opposite = ['nice']
searchfor = ['bad']


d = a[a.str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)) & a.str.contains('|' .join(opposite))]
print(d)
2    this is nice and bad
Name: mention, dtype: object
```